# In Excel, how can I make a list selection update the value of another list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an ID and Name in columns A and B. Columns C and D are drop-downs where the possible values are the values of ID and Name.

[image: Column C is a selection of IDs][image: Column D is a drop-down of names]

When an ID is selected in column C, I want column D to be automatically updated to its corresponding name and vice versa. For example:

- If "KA12" is selected in C2, then D2 should be updated to "Karen"
- If "Calvin" is selected in D2, then C2 should be updated to "CA999"
- The selections in row 5 of my screenshots should be impossible. If "KA12" is selected in C5, then D5 should be updated to "Karen". And if D5 was then changed to "John", then C5 should be updated to J123.

This is a diluted example. In the "real world" this is to fill out information on the second sheet of a workbook based on values of the first sheet. A user may be more familiar with the IDs than the Name or the other way around, so I want them to have the option to select either but not mismatching values.

Is it possible to achieve this without any VBA?

Comment: No, it is not possible without vba.  It would create circular references

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.